# how to get the status of commands executed inside ssh connection

Tags: ssh, unix

I have an ssh connection where I am running 2 commands.
I want to know the status of each command after execution.
the code is like below:

```
ssh   $username@$server -t  <<'XXX'
command 1
command 2
XXX
```

I want to know the status after executing command 1 and again the staus of command 2 after executing that.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: shouldn't that first line be rearranged to be more like `username@server$ssh -t  <<'XXX'` I haven't tried the command with those parameters and that after it. But clearly there should only be one $ in that line and the ssh should be after it! And the user@host before the $ is just a prompt, you could remove it and just say $. so   $ssh -t << 'XXX' though as I say, i haven't tried that command.

Comment: i have asked for how to get the execution status of command 1 and 2. So can you please answer that if possible

Comment: @barlop There's nothing wrong with `ssh $username@$server`. "$username" and "$server" are shell variables.

Comment: @Kenster ah, ok

Answer (score 0):

The remote shell can access the exit status and output it for you:

```
ssh   $username@$server -t  <<'XXX'
command 1
echo command 1 exit status $?
command 2
echo command 2 exit status $?
XXX
```

An exit status of 0 generally indicates that the command succeeded, while non-zero values indicate failure. But the specific commands that you're running might behave differently.